# Exception has occurred: error mpg123_seek: Invalid RVA mode. (code 12)

Tags: python, pygame

I am recording audio using sounddevice and I want to play it through a virtual audio cable through pygame, I keep receiving this error `Exception has occurred: error mpg123_seek: Invalid RVA mode. (code 12)`

My code is below:

```
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import random
import pygame
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init(devicename='CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)')

fs = 44100  # Sample rate
seconds = 00.1  # Duration of recording


def main():
    for x in range(10000):
        number = random.randint(1,9999999)


        myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
        sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished
        write(f'output/output{str(number)}.mp3', fs, myrecording)  # Save as WAV file `

        # PLAY MIC SOUND HERE
        pygame.mixer.music.load(f'output/output{str(number)}.mp3') #Load the mp3  
        pygame.mixer.music.play() #Play it
        time.sleep(00.1)

main()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues.

The first is that `scipi.io.wavefile.write()` only writes an uncompressed WAV file (ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html ).  You might name it `.mp3`, but it's not compressed that way.

The next issue is that `pygame.mixer.music` will not `.load()` uncompressed WAV files.  So... what to do...

One work-around is to use the base `pygame.mixer`, which is happy to load uncompressed WAV.  And while I don't have an 'CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)' device, I do get a nice file of silence, which I validated with the sound-editing program Audacity, and this seems to play OK.

```
import sounddevice as sd
from scipy.io.wavfile import write
import pygame
import time
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init(devicename='CABLE Input (VB-Audio Virtual Cable)')

fs = 44100  # Sample rate
seconds = 00.1  # Duration of recording


def main():
    for x in range(10000):
        number = random.randint(1,9999999)

        myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=2)
        sd.wait()  # Wait until recording is finished

        filename = f'output/output{str(number)}.wav'
        write(filename, fs, myrecording)  # Save as uncompressed WAV file 

        # PLAY MIC SOUND HERE
        print( "Playing ["  + filename + "]" )

        #pygame.mixer.music.load(filename) #Load the wav
        #pygame.mixer.music.play() #Play it
        #while ( pygame.mixer.music.get_busy() ):  # wait for the sound to end
        #    time.sleep(00.1)

        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(filename) #Load the wav
        sound.play() #Play it
        while ( pygame.mixer.get_busy() ):  # wait for the sound to end
            time.sleep(00.1)

main()
```

Comment: The code works but it is meant to play the audio through the microphone. If you would like to test it, VB-Cable is a virtual audio cable that you can download: https://vb-audio.com/Cable/

Comment: I updated my code to get it working, thanks!